# How can I record the sound that a javasound application is currently playing?

Tags: java, javasound

I have two wav files that I'd like to simulate generating at different points in 3D space, as heard from a rectangular 4 channel mic array.  That is, the ideal output will be either a single 4 channel wav file or 4 single channel wav files that are known to be synchronized.

My current approach isn't all that great, but it could in principle work.  I have the two sounds playing from their positions in a jReality simulation (chosen merely because I already had a jReality simulation handy).  There are two problems with this:  A) jReality only supports a single microphone location and B) it goes directly from jReality to javasound and from there out my speakers.  To solve A, I should be able to position the mic, take a recording, move the mic and repeat.  Unfortunately I don't know how to solve B, I do know that the recording has to be from within my java code because that's the only way to synchronize it.

So the question is twofold, first, is there a better way to simulate the audio mixing and attenuation?  And secondly, is there a way to intercept things that have been sent to javasound and store them to files?

Comment: I have no idea if this would work, but could you run two instances of jReality? One for each mic?

Comment: I could spin up 4 jRealitys (1 for each mic) within the same process, but if they all pipe into javasound the output would end up being stereo instead of 4 channel.

Answer (score 1):

It is fully possible to read from four sources (AudioInputLines) and work on them at the "per frame" level. Usually coders have a while loop for reading incoming audio data. With each buffer read (for four sources, you would have four buffers) you would decode the incoming bytes into sound data, apply your mixing algorithm, and then reconvert the result back to bytes as per your audio format.

If you wrap the above in a TargetDataLine, it will be possible to record it.

The Java Sound Tutorials cover this in a sort of "big picture" manner, but if you haven't come across the main concepts before (on using javax.sound.sampled library) it will be worth a look.

Comment: That's the reverse of the data flow I'm looking for.  I'm not trying to read from 4 channels, I'm trying to _create_ 4 channels.  It's not my code that does the mixing, it's jReality that does the mixing.  I'm not trying to read from input lines, the audio I want is sent into output lines and I don't know how to get at it.  Am I missing something in your response?

Comment: Sorry for the mixup! I don't know about jReality. I would read the two stereo inputs via two AudioInputLines, both read in the same while loop described above, and converting to sound frames. Then, do your distance/power computations for the 4 mike locations, and convert back to bytes using a format with 4 channels. Do you know how to make your own format? To store the resulting 4-channel wav, again, wrap everything in a TargetDataLine. HTH!

Comment: Ah, so just do the whole thing myself?  That's an option I suppose, I tend to prefer using libraries if at all possible (when I look at http://www3.math.tu-berlin.de/jreality/mediawiki/index.php/The_jReality_audio_rendering_pipeline I see a lot of places I could screw up)... but I'm happy to switch which library I use if you have/can-find a better suggestion.

Comment: I don't know of a library where exactly what you want is prebuilt. But that doesn't mean there isn't one, only that I'm been very DIY on this technology. "TinySound" https://github.com/finnkuusisto/TinySound has source code and does per-frame mixing, but on a very simple level: blending multiple sources for a stereo output. You might check out JAudioLibs, Neil really knows his stuff. http://code.google.com/p/java-audio-utils/ I haven't fully explored his library but he's given me great advice while I've been building my own. Good luck! Maybe someone else will provide a library link.